# How to use Google App Engine in conjunction with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been using Firebase for a long time and it's great, however I need more power for certain things.

At the moment, I have a function in Cloud Functions for Firebase to do some video processing and I need more power. I have heard Google's App Engine is better for this kind of solution and I've been experimenting with App Engine with my Google Cloud project.

I went to deploy my first Node.JS app function to App Engine and it seemed as if it was going to overwrite my existing functions I have. I have lots of functions, and code in Firebase for my app and my website to talk to one another, so I'd like to keep and leave my Firebase stuff alone.

I'm just wondering, how I'd use App Engine (and maybe some other higher end Google Cloud products) alongside Firebase without interfering or changing one another, but using the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine is an entirely different product than Cloud Functions.  Anything you deploy to App Engine will not affect what you've already deployed to Cloud Functions, and the same applies in reverse. You can use both products in tandem with no conflicts.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/serverless-options/), you can find more details related to the serverless environments options that you have. It would be helpful to read about each of them and choose whatever fits your needs better.

Comment: Will I be able to reference one other, cloud functions to the app engine and vice versa? So if a cloud function gets triggered I can call a function in the app engine?

Comment: Yes, if your project is on a billing plan.  The best thing to do here is actually try it to see how things work.